# Unable to start rails server after install mysql@5.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I recently uninstalled the mysql@5.6 and installed mysql@5.7. But now when I start the rails server, I get the following error.

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
```

It is still searching for mysql@5.6 that is why it is failing. I have started the mysql server and even added the below line in my `.zshrc` file

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Please let me know if someone knows how to fix this.

I have the following file present:

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uninstall the mysql2 gem that was build against your old MySQL version with

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

And reinstall it with

```
Bundle install
```